# delete correct entry in MySQL table in react javaScript

Tags: mysql, reactjs, backend

I'm trying to delete a specific entry in a MySQL table in react JavaScript in the front end it shows that it is deleted but when I go to the database it always deletes the first one, what am i doing wrong?, here is my code...

```
handleMedicationDelete = async (i) => {
const meds = Object.assign([], this.state.medications);
const { user, medications } = this.state;

await postFetch(`/bgtracker/medications/delete/${user.id}`, {
  id: medications[i].id,
}).catch((err) => console.log(err));
meds.splice(i, 1);
this.setState({ medications: meds });
};
```

and here is code for route...

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const connection = require('../../../db/Connection');

router.post('/:user_id', (req, res) => {
const sql = `DELETE FROM medications WHERE user_id=${req.params.user_id}\
ORDER BY id LIMIT 1;\
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpmedications(
    user_id int not null,
    name varchar(25) not null,
    dose int not null,
    quantity int not null,
    prescriber varchar(25) not null,
    am int not null,
    noon int not null,
    evening int not null,
    bed int not null);\
  INSERT INTO tmpmedications(user_id, name, dose, quantity, prescriber,
    am, noon, evening, bed)\
  SELECT user_id, name, dose, quantity, prescriber,
    am, noon, evening, bed 
    FROM medications;\
  DROP TABLE medications;\
CREATE TABLE medications(
    id int not null auto_increment,
    user_id int not null,
    name varchar(25) not null,
    dose int not null,
    quantity int not null,
    prescriber varchar(25) not null,
    am int not null,
    noon int not null,
    evening int not null,
    bed int not null,
  primary key (id),
  foreign key(user_id) references users(id));\
INSERT INTO medications(user_id, name, dose, quantity, prescriber,
    am, noon, evening, bed)\
SELECT user_id, name, dose, quantity, prescriber, am, noon, evening,
 bed
  FROM tmpmedications;\
DROP TEMPORARY TABLE tmpmedications`;

connection.query(sql, (err, results, rows) => {
if (err) {
  return res.send(err.message);
} else {
  res.send(`Successfully Deleted Row ${req.params.id}`);
}
});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: What do you mean by it deleted the first one? Are you able to show some screenshots of the output?

Comment: when I delete the last one of the table in program it still deletes the first one out of the database

Comment: I'm trying to delete the one in the database that corresponds with the table in program

Comment: What output do you get in res.send?

Comment: when I delete the last one in the program table it comes up with id=12

Comment: Can you run a `Select` query in your database, make sure to use `Order by id limit 1`. Does it show the value you're expecting?

Comment: This is not a React problem.

Comment: I get the first one when i do order by id limit 1.. so what would I have to put to get the specific id I want?

Comment: Are you sure its UserId? Not Id? I think it's best you show your database structure for us to understand the problem little deeper.

Comment: here is my table structure for medications table
create table medications (
 id int not null auto_increment,
 user_id int not null,
 name text not null,
 dose int not null,
 quanity int not null,
    prescriber text not null,
    am int not null,
    noon int not null,
    evening int not null,
    bed int not null,
 primary key (id),
 foreign key(user_id) references users(id)
);

Comment: i figured it out